# Regex validation for asp textbox control

Tags: asp.net, regex, textbox

I have 2 textbox asp controls:  Phone and Time.
Phone should have format: +7 (xxx) xx-xx

Time is a float and should have value between 1.0  to 40.0  (for example 20.5)

How to realize it in regular validation section?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this pattern will help you:

+7 (\d\d\d) (\d\d)-(\d\d)